Adding 'Envelope Attachments' to a Docusign envelope through the API/SDK
I'm using the Docusign C# SDK to create and send envelopes. At the time of creation I would like to add an 'Envelope Attachment' to include some internal metadata about the envelope. (I want to use it later after receiving notification of envelope completion via the Docusign Connect webhook).
The problem is that the documentation is vague about what is needed to do this. I've got an envelopeDefintion object with the envelope definition and am doing the following to add the attachment:
envelopeDefinition.EnvelopeAttachments = 
  [
    new Attachment(AttachmentId: "1", Label: "Test Label", Name: "Test Name", AttachmentType: ".txt", Data: testDocumentAsBase64String),
  ];

The envelope gets created as expected, but no attachment is created. The documentation doesn't say what values are accepted for most of the fields so I've tried various combinations with no luck. Any ideas why this wouldn't be working? The envelope is being created with an initialStatus of "Sent".
I read something about this being available in draft or in-process, but I would think that "Sent" would count as in process. Or do I need to create a draft with the attachment, and then send separately?
To be clear since other similar posts seem to get signer and envelope attachments confused, I'm aware that these types of attachments would only be available through the API. After creating the envelope, querying the API for envelope attachments returns an empty data set, which is how I'm verifying that no attachment was created.

"draft" envelopes are only until you send them. You cannot do this for "sent" envelopes even if not yet completed. They have to be corrected for that, and correct is a special status of the envelope where it's locked.
So, you can try to do this when the envelope is in draft, still you would need a second API call.
Or, you can use text custom fields, and then do it in the same API call when the envelope is created (and sent).
Text Custom fields are a collection of name/value strings that you can add to your envelope for any sort of meta-data.
Envelope Custom fields can also be added from the UI - https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=ywu1578456351241.html&_LANG=enus&language=en_US&rsc_301=
Or from the API using code like this:
Code example with step-by-step instructions - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-custom-tab-values/
C# Code snippet:
    envelopeDefinition.CustomFields = new CustomFields();
    envelopeDefinition.CustomFields.TextCustomFields = new List<TextCustomField>();
    var customField = new TextCustomField();
    customField.Name = "my custom field";
    customField.Value = "The value of that field";
    envelopeDefinition.CustomFields.TextCustomFields.Add(customField);


I believe your thinking of 'Signer Attachments' which are different. From the documentation:
"Envelope attachments are files that an application can include in an envelope. They are not visible to envelope senders or recipients, and they are not converted to PDF. Envelope attachments are available only through the eSignature REST API's EnvelopeAttachments resource. There is no user interface in the Docusign web application for them."

I stand corrected. Still, why not use text custom fields?

BTW, the issue you may have could very well be related to you not doing that on a draft envelope, let me update my answer

Updated my answer

Interesting. It's unfortunate that the API and SDK make it appear as though the attachment is created but it just never happens when initially creating an envelope. Even creating the envelope in draft mode doesn't add the attachment through the envelope 'create' endpoint. It appears has to be added after the fact with a put request to the envelopes attachments endpoint. Also, I was able to attach it to a 'sent' envelope in the same way so I'm a bit confused about what you mean with draft vs. sent for these attachments

To answer your other question, custom fields won't work for our use case. We have too much metadata (custom fields are limited to my knowledge) and don't want them to be available to users via the UI. So the hope is to attach a small json file with the metadata as an envelope attachment.

ok, did you try to use the attachment in a draft envelope? that didn't work either?

EnvelopeAttachments is the right approach, based on the fact that you have more metadata than an envelope custom field can hold.  If it is all textual, e.g. json or xml, you can add it directly.  Otherwise, it can be attached as base64encoded text.
EnvelopeAttachments are metadata and not seen by the signers/recipients.  It is just attached to the envelope to "ride along".

See the answer by Arunjith ps for the correct way to instantiate envelopeDefinition.EnvelopeAttachments.

try following steps
      Attachment attachment = new Attachment
    {
        AttachmentId = "1",
        Label = "Test Label",
        Name = "Test Name",
        AttachmentType = ".txt",
        Data = testDocumentAsBase64String
    };

  envelopeDefinition.EnvelopeAttachments = new List<Attachment> { attachment };

or try EnvelopeCustomMetadata
and also set status
envelopeDefinition.Status = "created" // set before calling api this will created for draft, if you want to send separately later

